# ScaleY tranformation not working

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component that I want to display or hide when the parent div that wraps it is clicked.
I am trying to add an animation for both when it appears and when it disappears.

At the moment it works only when it appears, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

## React component

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './styles.css';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

export default function toggleableElement({ isOpen, content }) {
    const animatedAnswerStyle = cx({
        animatedAnswer: true,
        opened: isOpen,
        closed: !isOpen,
    });
    return (
        <div className={animatedAnswerStyle}>
            {
                isOpen &&
                 <p> { content } </p>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

## Style

```
.animatedAnswer {
    transform: scaleY(0);
}

.opened {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    tranform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.closed {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    tranform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);    
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add the transition in the ruleset for .animatedAnswer, instead of .opened and .closed?

Comment: With only one ruleset how can I make it scale from 0 to 1 when opened and back to 0 when closed?

Comment: I meant putting only the 'transition' declaration in .animatedAnswer, keeping 'transform' and 'transform-origin' in the two other rulesets.

Comment: Oh I see. No, I solved using this approach: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/

Comment: Ok, nice that you were able to fix it :).

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
.animatedAnswer {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
}

.opened {
  max-height: 800px; // a big value
}
```